# HBase - Playframework get byte[] value as image and show it on website

Tags: java, playframework, hbase

I am working on Play Framework 2.2.6, HBase 0.94.27 and Solr 5.5.0(I did not show any solr code in my question.). I am trying to render first page of pdf as image and show that image on search list like [amazon](http://s31.postimg.org/ifprau2u3/amazon_Search.jpg) or [ebay](http://s31.postimg.org/c0cy8xryz/ebay_Search.jpg) does. I first parse the image and convert it to byte[] for storing it in HBase.

I can successfully index rendered image as byte in HBase, but I cannot show it on html side. I am getting error: `Error found: javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!`
.

Program renders first page as image and converts is to `byte[] byteImage` and indexes that byte variable in HBase.

Search Part:

```
final static List<Searching> searchList = new ArrayList<Searching>();
//Searching class has string variables for title, content, number of pages and picture.
searchList.clear();
Form<Searching> filledForm = searchForm.bindFromRequest();
Searching searched = filledForm.get();

try {
     HTable hTable = new HTable(hConn.config, "books");
     Get g = new Get(Bytes.toBytes(searched.outputId));
    g.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("picture"), Bytes.toBytes("raw"));
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result result = hTable.get(g);
     if (result.containsColumn(Bytes.toBytes("picture"), Bytes.toBytes("raw"))) {
                byte[] byteOutputPicture = result.getNoVersionMap().get(Bytes.toBytes("picture")).get(Bytes.toBytes("raw"));
                BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(byteOutputPicture+".png"));
                java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ImageIO.write(image, "png", baos);
                byte[] res=baos.toByteArray();
                searched.outputPicture = com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util.Base64.encode(baos.toByteArray());
                //outputPicture is a String variable in Searching class.
     }

                searchList.add(searched);
                hTable.close();
 } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Error found: " + e);
 }
```

search.scala.html:

```
@(searchList: List[Searching])
...

<body>
  @for(search <- searchList) {
     <img src="data:image/png;base64,@search.outputPicture" alt="IMG">
  }
</body>
```

**Update 1:** I changed html side and added some codes according to [this website](http://mrbool.com/how-to-convert-image-to-byte-array-and-byte-array-to-image-in-java/25136), but I still am getting `Error found: java.lang.NullPointerException`. I cannot be sure where the error comes from, because program stops somehow.

**Update 2:** After changing some codes, new error appeared: `Error found: javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that I need to use `ByteArrayInputStream()` instead of `File()` in `read()` function.

[Result on my web page](http://s31.postimg.org/bjce3g0hn/result_TT.jpg)